# Node.js multipart form error parsing the object from string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, multipartform-data, meanjs

I am trying to read data from a multipart form in Node.js

```
 exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        var file = files.file[0];
        var contentType = file.headers['content-type'];
        var data = JSON.parse(fields.data);
        console.log(data);
        var application = new Application(data.application);
        //application.position = req.position;

        application.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(application);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Before creating the object, I print out a console.log to understand what is the JSON object looking like

```
{ application: '{"firstName":"s"}' }
```

When I try to instantiate a new Application, I get the following error:

```
/home/maurizio/Workspace/glasswindow/glasswindow-mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:158
      if (obj && '_id' in obj) continue;
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {"firstName":"s"}
```

Any idea why? And how can I use the JSON object to create the Application object?

Comment: Don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON strings. You have to parse your `'{"firstName":"s"}'` string because you can handle it as object.

Comment: Is it not what... JSON.parse(fields.data); does?

Comment: You posted `{ application: '{"firstName":"s"}' }`. If that's not your data, please edit the question.